# android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter getItem(int position) being called twice?

Tags: android

I have a view pager which contains a fragment. When the fragment pager adapter first gets instantiated, the getItem(int position) method that must be implemented gets called twice, which is causing trouble in the Fragment since I am getting data based on the position. So for example, a LOG print reveals that it is first position 0, then position 1.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I am following the example here: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `getItem(int position)` is called for loading (attaching) the fragment to its position in the fragment pager. By default, not only the visible fragment is loaded, but also the next one and previous one. So when you scroll to the 2nd 'page', you will see it will load the 3rd. When you go to the 3rd, it will unload the 1st fragment, and load the 4th. When you go back to the 2nd fragment, it wil load the 1st fragment again. And so on.

Comment: I'm inflating a ListView in the OnCreateView method of my Fragment with data based on the index of the page. The first page contains the data of the second screen (wrong), and the second screen contains the same data (correct). The third screen contains correct data, then when I go back to the first screen the data is correct. So basically my only problem is when the fragment first loads, it is displaying the wrong data.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, but stopped working with ViewPager since it was not able to show multiple pages at a time.. (just what I needed) So the reason why it shows the 2nd position while at the 1ste position is in my answer, but do no have an answer for why it is displaying the wrong data..

Comment: Maybe what you are doing wrong, is accessing the 'current position' from outside the adapter? By doing this, you would access not the current visible position, but the last loaded position.. which is not the same. You should pass the position in get item, to the creation of the fragment, inside the getItem method. Just like in the example.Is that what you are doing?